# Simple Calculator using HTML forms in python django

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-views, forms, http-post

Below is my html form:

```
<form id="calci_form" method="get" action="#">
 <input type="hidden" name="prev_val" value="{{prev_val}}"></input>
 <input type="hidden" name="curr_val" value="{{curr_val}}"></input>
 <input type="hidden" name="op_sign" value="{{opsign}}"></input>
 <div id="calculator">
 <table id="tableCalci">
 <tr  id="row1">
 <td colspan="4"><input type="text" value="0" class="display" name="user_input">{{result}}</input></td>
</tr>
 <tr>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
<tr class="hover">
<td><button id="7" name="numval" value="7" type="submit"></button></td>
<td><button id="8" name="numval" value="8" type="submit"></button></td>
<td><button id="9" name="numval" value="9" type="submit"></button></td>
<td><button id="plus" name="sym" type="submit" value="add">&plus;</button>      
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
 <tr class="hover">
<td><button id="4" name="numval" value="4" type="submit"></button></td>
<td><button id="5" name="numval" value="5" type="submit"></button></td>
<td><button id="6" name="numval" value="6" type="submit"></button></td>
<td><button id="minus" name="sym" value="minus" type="submit">&minus;   
</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
 <tr class="hover">
 <td><button id="1" name="numval" value="1" type="submit"></button></td>
 <td><button id="2" name="numval" value="2" type="submit"></button></td>
 <td><button id="3" name="numval" value="3" type="submit"></button></td>
 <td><button id="times" name="sym" value="times" type="submit">&times;  
 </button></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="hover">
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
 <td><button id="0" name="numval" value="0" type="submit"></button></td>
 <td><button id="equal" name="sym" type="submit">&equals;</button></td>
 <td><button id="divide"; name="sym" type="submit" value="divide">&divide;   
 </button></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </div>
</form>
```

Views.py file:

```
if 'sym' in request.GET:
        if request.GET['sym'] == 'add':
            first=request.GET['result']
            opsign='\&plus;'
            return render(request,'calculator.html',{'result':first,'prev_val':first,'curr_val':second,'opsign':opsign}) 
elif request.GET['sym'] == '=':
            if 'prev_val' in request.GET and request.GET['prev_val']:
                first=request.GET['prev_val']
            if 'result' in request.GET and request.GET['result']:
                second=request.GET['result']    
            try:
                result=add(10,20)
            except ValueError:
                err="Error: Incorrect Number"
            except ZeroDivisionError:
                err="Error: Division by zero"
            return render(request,'calculator.html',{'result':result,'error':err}) 
        else:
            return render(request,'calculator.html',{'error':'No Operation selected'})
```

Solution required: When i click the "Plus" button or "Equal" button the above mentioned function does not invoke at all. THe controller is not passed from HTML page to the above function in the views.py file. Where am i making the mistake and why the controller is not passing control to the function. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For starters i think you are sending a POST and checking for GET.

Comment: Do you have your view created or are those if's floating around?

Answer (score 1):

is your view getting called or you're not able to get any result.

One thing even if view gets control, is sure that your code will break when `sym` is =
because it will be handled in the first `if` and it doesn't handle =

If your form isn't submitted, i think you need to handle it through Javascript and AJAX.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I came to know about it after it threw an eror back.

Answer (score 0):

In my view.py file i had written the operations such as add,sub,mul in the end. So, i just put them at the top of the file below import. It worked.

Views.py file:

```
from django.shorcuts import render

def add(a,b):
 return a+b

def mul(a,b):
 return a*b

def sub(a,b):
 return a-b

def operation(request):
  if 'sym' in request.GET:
        if request.GET['sym'] == 'add':
            first=request.GET['result']
            opsign='\&plus;'
            return render(request,'calculator.html',{'result':first,'prev_val':first,'curr_val':second,'opsign':opsign}) 
  elif request.GET['sym'] == '=':
        if 'prev_val' in request.GET and request.GET['prev_val']:
            first=request.GET['prev_val']
        if 'result' in request.GET and request.GET['result']:
            second=request.GET['result']    
        try:
            result=add(10,20)
        except ValueError:
            err="Error: Incorrect Number"
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            err="Error: Division by zero"
        return render(request,'calculator.html',{'result':result,'error':err}) 
    else:
        return render(request,'calculator.html',{'error':'No Operation selected'})
```